# Plot a poisson distribution graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I would like to plot the Poisson function in Python using Matplotlib. The function is (exp(-5)*5^x)/factorial(x)

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
d = []

for i in t:
    p = pow(5,i)
    q = p/math.factorial(i)
    d.append(q)

plt.plot( t, np.exp(-5)*d, 'bs')
plt.show()
```

But I get this error."Only size^1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". How can I plot this graph? Thanks in advance

Comment: Should it be `pow(5,i)` and `factorial(i)` instead of `t`?

Answer (score 3):

i think your function is not right: it's `exp(-5)`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import factorial

t = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
d = np.exp(-5)*np.power(5, t)/factorial(t)

plt.plot(t, d, 'bs')
plt.show()
```

[image: poisson distribution]

Comment: Note that `scipy.misc.factorial` is deprecated and is, as of 1.0, `scipy.special.factorial`.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is probably that you are using 't' instead of 'i' in your loop. However, you may want to avoid mixing python lists with numpy arrays. You could do it like,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
x = np.power(t, 5)
y = scipy.misc.factorial(t)

plt.plot( t, x / y, 'bs')
plt.show()
```